# Repopulate a newer array with values from an older array- php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am trying to update values from array1 with a newly ordered array2 and output the final array as array2. I have been tying to figure this out for days now but cannot seem to get it. I am new to php as you can most likely tell. Can anyone help me?

Here are the two arrays- 'array1' is first and 'array2' follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => bbb
            [hammer] => $1,000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => ccc
            [hammer] => $678
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => aaa
            [hammer] => $222
        )

) Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => aaa
            [hammer] => GBP 135
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => bbb
            [hammer] => GBP 610
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => ccc
            [hammer] => GBP 413
        )

)
```

Now my code tries to update the newly reordered 'id' values in the second array with the 'hammer' values from the first array. Here is my code:

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $val) {
    $a = $array2[$key]['id'];
    $hammer_a = $array2[$key]['hammer'];

    foreach($array1 as $key => $val) { 
        $b = $array1[$key]['id'];
        if($a===$b){ 
            $hammer_b = $array1[$key]['hammer']; 
            $array2[$key]['hammer'] = $hammer_b;
        }
    } 
}
```

However as this code stands I am left with an undesired result below. I would like 'id' 'aaa' to have its original 'hammer' value of $222 and so on for the other 'id's:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => aaa
            [hammer] => $1,000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => bbb
            [hammer] => $678
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => ccc
            [hammer] => $222
        )

)
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you perhaps post an example of the result you'd like to have? If I understand well, all you want to do is sort your array1 based on array2's ids order??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of `$key` and `$val` in the second loop. They are overriding each other.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. This is the last problem I have before finishing a painlful php entry level experience. With no one else but this community to ask, I feel lucky. Your answer is perfect. And I am now more aware of the importance of paying attention to the naming of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use $key in your inner foreach loop. You want the key for array2.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this option, with a lot less code:

```
$items[0] = array('id'=>'bbb','hammer'=>'$1,000');
$items[1] = array('id'=>'ccc','hammer'=>'$678');
$items[2] = array('id'=>'aaa','hammer'=>'$222');

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['id'], $b['id']);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($items);

usort($items, "cmp");

var_dump($items);
echo '</pre>';
```